# docker-compose: run rails db:setup and rake tasks to init data

Tags: docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5, dockerfile

I can't find the way to execute the following commands from a `docker-compose.yml` file:

- `rails db:setup`
- `rails db:init_data`.

I tried to do that as follows and it failed:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    links:
      - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
      - .env/development/web
    command: ["rails", "db:setup"]
    command: ["rails", "db:init_data"]
  redis:
    image: redis
  database:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Any idea on what's going wrong here ? Thank you.
The code source is on the [GitHub](https://github.com/belgoros/myapp).

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things in my opinion:

1. Change `command:` to the following line, because two commands are not allowed in compose file:

```
    command: 
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - |
          rails db:setup
          rails db:init_data
```

---

2. Use **supervisord** app: [supervisord web page](http://supervisord.org/)

Comment: what does the pipe `|` sign mean ? Should I have exactly the same indentation as you posted (rails commands are indented more than the `|` symbol.

Comment: Pipe lets you write in several lines different commands. Identation is not a requirement, but a recommendation

Comment: It failed. I changed for `rails db:reset` followed by `rails db:init_data`. The logs created the tables twice (why?) and the service didn't started: `myapp_web_1 exited with code 0`

Comment: If it failed, is that is not possible to execute both for external reasons to docker-compose, because it works, I've checked with for example an apache2 start an another process. Try to put both in a bash script and execute this script as a command.

Comment: As far as I could understand from docker-compose DOCs, if we sepcify `command` option in `web` service in `docker-compose.yml`, this would have overridden the CMD instruction specified in the Dockerfile I defined: `CMD ["rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]`. I think that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to remove `CMD` commad from `Dockerfile` because using `command` option in `docker-compose.yml` would have overridden `CMD` command.
So, Docker file will look like that:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1

LABEL maintainer="DECATHLON"

RUN apt-get update -yqq
RUN apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends nodejs

COPY Gemfile* /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN bundle install

COPY . /usr/src/app/
```

Then add `command` option to `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    links:
      - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
      - .env/development/web
    command:
      - |
        rails db:reset
        rails db:init_data
        rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  redis:
    image: redis
  database:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db-data:
```

If the above solution does not work for somebody, there is an alternative solution:

Create a shell script in the project route and name it `entrypoint.sh`, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash  
set -e  
bundle exec rails db:reset
bundle exec rails db:migrate  
exec "$@"
```

Declare `entrypoint` option in `dpcker-compose` file:

v

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - ./entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
      - .env/development/web
    command: ['./wait-for-it.sh', 'database:5432', '--', 'bundle', 'exec', 'rails', 's', '-p', '3000', '-b', '0.0.0.0']
  database:
    image: postgres:9.6
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db-data:
```

I also user [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script to ensure the DB is started.

Hope this helps. I pushed the modifications to the Github repo. Sorry for some extra letters left in the text before code blocks, - for some unknown reasons, the code markdown didn't work, so I left them to get it working.